# ¿Hay alguna forma de obtener el angulo/argumento de una funcion trigonometrica?

Tags: python, funciones

Esta duda es simple, pero no eh encontrado una forma de hacerlo:
Supongamos que introduzco la función `sin(3x+1)`, ¿hay alguna forma de obtener el `3x+1`?

Ya probé usando `asin(sin(3x+1))` pero ni lo simplifica ni hace nada, la salida es la misma `asin(sin(3x+1))`

De igual manera probé usando `simplify` o `trigsimp` pero la salida sigue igual `asin(sin(3x+1))`

Comment: Como le pasas a la funcion sin() el 3x+1? ¿Podrias compartir algo de código para verlo?

Comment: `import sympy as sp
x = sp.Symbol('x', real=True)

b=sin(3*x+1)
pol=asin(b)

display(pol)`

de aquí la salida vuelve a ser:
`asin(sin(3x+1))`
No es mucho, solo estaba haciendo pruebas para el programa que ando creando

Comment: Dado el resultado de la función, puedes obtener el argumento de manera numérica (es decir, el ángulo que se corresponde con ese resultado), justamente aplicando la función inversa. Pero no puedes obtener como tal el valor literal `'3x + 1'`.

Comment: Ya se me ocurrió una forma xD, es complicada pero funcionaria para casos sencillos tipo sin(5x) o cos(10x).

Se pueden derivar las funciones, separar en factores y con eso obtendría el 5 o el 10 posteriormente si es asi de sencillo multiplicar dicho factor por x y listo.

Si el caso es mas elaborado como el de arriba sen(3x+1) o cualquier angulo con variables, podría derivarlos también, y plantear una ecuación diferencial igual separando los factores, de ahí es integrar aplicar una condicion y listo xD

Comment: @LoboFJP. Edita tu pregunta para mencionar el hecho de que estás trabajando con SymPy.sin(), no math.sin()

Answer (score 1):

El atributo `args` contiene los argumentos de la expresión como tupla:

```
import sympy as sp

x = sp.Symbol("x", real=True)
y = sp.Symbol("y", real=True)
c = sp.sin(x + y)

# c_args es una tupla conteniendo los argumentos
c_args = c.args
print(c_args)
c_args = c_args[0]   # Primer elemento en la tupla.
c_x = c_args.args[0] 
c_y = c_args.args[1]
print("Type ", type(c_x), c_x)
print("Type ", type(c_y), c_y)
```

produce

```
(x + y,)
Type  <class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'> x
Type  <class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'> y
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono a la perfección